# How to convert string which not in correct time format to timestamp?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
str1='gio lug  7 00:36:20 CEST 2022'

str2='Wed Nov 17 12:43:56 zzz 2021'

str3='mi� nov 24 09:44:53 WET 2021'

str4='mer. sept. 23 11:58:21 CEST 2020'
```

I want to convert this string to timestamp
Can we do that?

I have tried this:

```py
from dateutil import parser

from datetime import datetime

i= 'gio lug  7 00:36:20 CEST 2022'

dt = parser.parse(i)

print(dt)

a=datetime.strftime(dt,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(a)
```

but it giving error like:[image]

Expected format is('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

Comment: Have you checked the docs? https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: You could create a timestamp for the `2022` part, but which month is it even supposed to be?

Comment: You need to pass more information to `parse`, to inform it about things like which timezone `CEST` is suppose to represent, that `'gio'` is the Italian abbreviation for Thursday, that `'lug'` is the Italian abbreviation for July, etc. `parse` can infer the *format* from the contents of the string, but it doesn't infer which *language* the various substrings are from.

Comment: (For example, `'thu jul 7 00:36:20 EST 2022'` parses just fine.)

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here. First of all, your dates are not in a specific format, you use different languages for the day of the week and the month. The numbering is also not consistent, sometime you have `.` after day and month, `mi�` doesn't mean anything. You must have a consistent format or map different formats to different strings. Check https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime for more info

Look at this example:

```
from datetime import datetime

import locale
#setting locale to Italian (gio, lug) is Giovedi Luglio I suppose...
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'it_IT.UTF-8')


str1='gio lug 07 00:36:20 CEST 2022' #changed lug 7 to lug 07 to have 2 digits day
str2='Wed Nov 17 12:43:56 zzz 2021'
str3='mi� nov 24 09:44:53 WET 2021'
str4='mer. sept. 23 11:58:21 CEST 2020'


dates = [str1, str2, str3, str4]
for date_string in dates:
    try:
        date_string = date_string.replace(".", "") #removing dots
        date = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")
        print(date)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

The output is the following:

```
2022-07-07 00:36:20  #good, it matches!
time data 'Wed Nov 17 12:43:56 zzz 2021' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'  #this is not Italian anymore, so it doesn't match
time data 'mi� nov 24 09:44:53 WET 2021' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'  #mi� is invalid, it doesn't match
time data 'mer sept 23 11:58:21 CEST 2020' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'  #mer is Italian (Mercoledi?) and Sept is English.. so again, doesn't match
```